# What does inc dword ptr gs : [] doing here?

Tags: windows, assembly, x86-64, windbg, dword

While debugging windows kernel with WinDbg,

I found following line:
**inc dword ptr gs : [2EB8h]**

Can someone please explain what this means? 
(Intel Syntax, x86, Windows-10)

[image]

Comment: The TIB is also known as the [thread environment block](https://www.geoffchappell.com/studies/windows/win32/ntdll/structs/teb/index.htm).  Oddly, the description there for the x64 TEB (as updated for Windows 10) only goes up to 0x1828.  Given that this is a hard coded address (ie not loaded from some tib variable), it sounds like there's something else being stored in the gs segment.  Or maybe geoffchappell isn't as complete as he thinks?

Answer (score 4):

The GS segment in **kernel** mode (windows x64) points to the Kernel Processor Control Region (**KPCR**).

You can dump it with the `!pcr` command:

```
kd> !pcr
KPCR for Processor 0 at fffff802fbd73000:
    Major 1 Minor 1
    NtTib.ExceptionList: fffff802fd6d8000
        NtTib.StackBase: fffff802fd6d9070
       NtTib.StackLimit: 0000000000b0e968
     NtTib.SubSystemTib: fffff802fbd73000
          NtTib.Version: 00000000fbd73180
      NtTib.UserPointer: fffff802fbd737f0
          NtTib.SelfTib: 000000007f005000

                SelfPcr: 0000000000000000
                   Prcb: fffff802fbd73180
                   Irql: 0000000000000000
                    IRR: 0000000000000000
                    IDR: 0000000000000000
          InterruptMode: 0000000000000000
                    IDT: 0000000000000000
                    GDT: 0000000000000000
                    TSS: 0000000000000000

          CurrentThread: ffffe001e41a3080
             NextThread: 0000000000000000
             IdleThread: fffff802fbde9740

              DpcQueue: Unable to read nt!_KDPC_DATA.DpcListHead.Flink @ fffff802fbd75f00
```

You can confirm that the KPCR really is pointed to by the `GS` segment register by reading the MSR (Model Specific Register) named `IA32_GS_BASE` (which value is 0xc0000101):

```
kd> rdmsr 0xc0000101
msr[c0000101] = fffff802`fbd73000
```

As you can see they both point, in my example, to 0xfffff802fbd73000.

The PCR is described by the `KPCR` structure:

```
kd> dt nt!_kpcr
   +0x000 NtTib            : _NT_TIB
   +0x000 GdtBase          : Ptr64 _KGDTENTRY64
   +0x008 TssBase          : Ptr64 _KTSS64
   +0x010 UserRsp          : Uint8B
   +0x018 Self             : Ptr64 _KPCR
   +0x020 CurrentPrcb      : Ptr64 _KPRCB //points to the _KPRCB member at 0x180
   +0x028 LockArray        : Ptr64 _KSPIN_LOCK_QUEUE
   +0x030 Used_Self        : Ptr64 Void
   +0x038 IdtBase          : Ptr64 _KIDTENTRY64
   +0x040 Unused           : [2] Uint8B
   +0x050 Irql             : UChar
   +0x051 SecondLevelCacheAssociativity : UChar
   +0x052 ObsoleteNumber   : UChar
   +0x053 Fill0            : UChar
   +0x054 Unused0          : [3] Uint4B
   +0x060 MajorVersion     : Uint2B
   +0x062 MinorVersion     : Uint2B
   +0x064 StallScaleFactor : Uint4B
   +0x068 Unused1          : [3] Ptr64 Void
   +0x080 KernelReserved   : [15] Uint4B
   +0x0bc SecondLevelCacheSize : Uint4B
   +0x0c0 HalReserved      : [16] Uint4B
   +0x100 Unused2          : Uint4B
   +0x108 KdVersionBlock   : Ptr64 Void
   +0x110 Unused3          : Ptr64 Void
   +0x118 PcrAlign1        : [24] Uint4B
   +0x180 Prcb             : _KPRCB
```

As you can see the last field of the KPCR structure is another structure (**not** a pointer, but the structure itself) named `KPRCB` (which stands for Kernel Processor Control Block) at offset 0x180.

Here's the start of this structure:

```
kd> dt nt!_kprcb
   +0x000 MxCsr            : Uint4B
   +0x004 LegacyNumber     : UChar
   +0x005 ReservedMustBeZero : UChar
   +0x006 InterruptRequest : UChar
   +0x007 IdleHalt         : UChar
   +0x008 CurrentThread    : Ptr64 _KTHREAD
   +0x010 NextThread       : Ptr64 _KTHREAD
   +0x018 IdleThread       : Ptr64 _KTHREAD
   +0x020 NestingLevel     : UChar
   +0x021 ClockOwner       : UChar
   +0x022 PendingTickFlags : UChar
   +0x022 PendingTick      : Pos 0, 1 Bit
   +0x022 PendingBackupTick : Pos 1, 1 Bit
   +0x023 IdleState        : UChar
   +0x024 Number           : Uint4B
   ...
```

Above output truncated for brevity as this structure (and thus the PCR) is extremely large: the size of the PCR in windows 10 x64 is 0x8040 bytes (0x7EC0 for the KPRCB).

Given your 0x2eb8 offset in GS (which points to the PCR), we can just subtract the KPRCB offset from the PCR (0x180):

```
kd> ? 0x2eb8 - 0x180
Evaluate expression: 11576 = 00000000`00002d38
```

And then check which field is at offset 0x2d38 in the KPRCB:

```
0: kd> .shell -ci "dt nt!_kprcb" findstr /i 0x2d38
   +0x2d38 KeSystemCalls    : Uint4B
```

(note: you can just `dt nt!_kprcb` and look at offset 0x2d38).

So, the incremented field in your example is named `KeSystemCalls` and is a 32-bit field (`Uint4B`) as shown in your code.

**Field Usage**

Searching in the IDA disassembler (ntoskrnel.exe windows 10 - x64) we have 2 hits on the 0x2eb8 value:

- `KiSystemCall64`
- `VslpDispatchIumSyscall`

The first one is the "normal" syscall dispatcher while the second one is the syscall dispatcher for [IUM processes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/mt809132(v=vs.85).aspx) (aka Trustlets).

In both of these functions the use of the field is exactly the same (example in KiSystemCall64):

```
.text:0000000140187360    call    r10 ; perform syscall
.text:0000000140187363
.text:0000000140187363 loc_140187363:
.text:0000000140187363    inc     dword ptr gs:2EB8h ; increment syscall counter
```

So this field is simply a monotonic counter for the number of system calls that happened since the system boot.

Comment: @Nietsa KeSystemCalls is used to initalize Process->Cookie but it was some where in tha range of 600 in win7  if you say it is at 2d38 in windows 10 it has moved ahead a lot of disatance :)

Answer (score 1):

This Answer is Just an Extension to Nietsa's answer 
Apart From Being used to Create Process->cookie
KeSystemCalls member in **poi(nt!KiProcessorBlock)** Structure

```
kd> ?? @@masm(poi(nt!KiProcessorBlock)) == @$prcb
bool true
kd> ? @$pcr
Evaluate expression: -2104316928 = 8292ac00
kd> ? @$pcr+120
Evaluate expression: -2104316640 = 8292ad20
kd> ? @$prcb
Evaluate expression: -2104316640 = 8292ad20
kd> ? poi(nt!KiProcessorBlock)
Evaluate expression: -2104316640 = 8292ad20
```

is also used to provide the performance counter values for

"\system\System Calls/sec"  data

```
C:\>powershell -c "&{get-counter -counter \"\System\System Calls/sec\"}"

Timestamp                 CounterSamples
                          144196.186791101
```

if one follows the pdh api

```
s = PdhCollectQueryData(hQuery);
```

one can observe the calls to NtQueryInformationSystem with SYSTEM_INFO_CLASS 2 == SystemPerformanceInformation  which Leads to nt!ExpQuerySystemInformation on the kernel side  filling the information from KPRCB

```
kd> # \+590h nt!ExpQuerySystemInformation l 600
nt!ExpQuerySystemInformation+0x57f:
82a01d73 038290050000    add     eax,dword ptr [edx+590h]

kd> ?? #FIELD_OFFSET(nt!_KPRCB , KeSystemCalls)
long 0n1424

kd> ? 0n1424
Evaluate expression: 1424 = 00000590  <<<< (windows 7 sp2 32 bit )
```

Comment: Hey @blabb ! Thanks a lot for your comment. And well done for your find, it's really interesting. You have my +1 :)